# How to add an option to a custom field (single select) in JIRA by Rest API

Tags: jira, rest, jira-rest-api

How can I add new options by REST API to a JIRA custom field (single select).

**Some Background Information:**
If I'm looking for `/rest/api/3/field` I find the field I want to edit as customfield_10030. It's a field I created in JIRA manually, and I'm able to see also the options by using other API endpoints. What doesn't work, is the following statement `rest/api/3/field/customfield_10030`. It responds with an `405 Method Not Allowed`. By this I can't use the contexts endpoint and by this I can also not use `PUT /rest/api/3/field/{fieldId}/context/{contextId}/option`. But why?

My goal is to add customers from my CRM to a single select customer custom field.